# Unable to return in out sequence while using clone mediator in ESB WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have taken an example from DZONE blog for the clone mediator but looks like I am making some mistake and unable to return in outsequece to process further.

Can anyone help in this?

```
  <proxy name="DSS_TrainDetailsProxy" transports="http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" statistics="enable">
    <target inSequence="DSS_TrainDetails_IN" outSequence="DSS_TrainDetails_OUT" faultSequence="CommonFaultHandler"/>
    <publishWSDL key="DSS_TrainDetails_wsdl"/>
</proxy>
 <localEntry key="DSS_TrainDetails_wsdl" src="file:repository/conf/train/wsdl/TrainDetails.wsdl"/>

<sequence name="DSS_TrainDetails_IN">
 <clone>
     <target>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="DSS_TrainDetails_EPR"/>
        </send>
    </target>
    <target>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="DSS_TrainDetails_EPR"/>
        </send>
    </target>
    <target>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="DSS_TrainDetails_EPR"/>
        </send>
    </target>
</clone>
```

```
    <sequence name="DSS_TrainDetails_OUT">

   <aggregate>
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete xmlns:tra="traindetails.co.nz" expression="//tra:TrainDetails">
            <log level="custom" separator=",">
                <property name="MessageFlow" value="======================= Sending Back the Aggregated Responses. ==============="/>
            </log>
            <log level="full" separator=","/>
            <enrich>
                <source xmlns:tra="traindetails.co.nz" clone="true" xpath="//tra:TrainDetails/tra:TrainsDetails"/>
                <target type="body" action="child"/>
            </enrich>
            <send/>
        </onComplete>
    </aggregate>

</sequence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi just wanted to let you know that Clone mediator worked for me :) I have made changes in IN sequence by below code I have removed "send" keyword from IN sequence :

```
<sequence name="DSS_TrainDetails_IN">
 <clone>
     <target>
            <endpoint key="DSS_TrainDetails_EPR"/>
    </target>
    <target>
            <endpoint key="DSS_TrainDetails_EPR1"/>
    </target>
    <target>
            <endpoint key="DSS_TrainDetails_EPR2"/>
    </target>
</clone>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that : remove your outSequence="DSS_TrainDetails_OUT" in your proxy def and inside your clone targets, change `<send>` to `<send receive="DSS_TrainDetails_OUT">`